# Extend a small js with a search for regex in the url

Tags: javascript

I would like to modify a little helper snippet in Google Tag Manager which purpose is to write a certain part of the url with GTM's build-in-var `{{Page URL}}` as a string into a custom dimension.

At the moment this is done with

```
function() {
var url = {{Page URL}};
if (url == "https://mywebsite.com/") {
    url = "home";
}
else {
    url = url.split("/"); 
    url = url[3].split("?");
    url = url[0];
}
return url; 
}
```

The goal is now to treat some url's with certain strings different from the other url's. All special url's have in common that they've got a unique combination of string+number which could easily be grabbed by a regex from the url. For example with `PID\d+`.

I'm relatively new to javascript and don't know how to integrate this additional condition. Should it be done by an „else if“ block for the regex? I've also tried to integrate another `if (url == /PID\d+/) {url = "foobar";}`. Any ideas how to achieve this?